# What does "F5" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A native of Hong Kong, John Chen studied in La Salle College in Hong
>   Kong up to F5 before he went to US and graduated from Northfield Mount
>   Hermon School, an elite prep school in Northfield, Massachusetts.

The paragraph is taken from [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_S._Chen). I'm wondering what F5 means in this context.

Comment: Judging by the context, I would assume it's that country's way of indicating which year of school a person is in (similar to the US _Freshman_, _Junior_, etc.). However, I don't know how **F5** would equate to the American school years.

Comment: Possibly 'Form Five' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_education#Hong_Kong

Comment: "Forms Four and Five students prepare for the Hong Kong Certificate of Education Examination (HKCEE), which takes place after Form Five." *ibid*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context I'd say it means some sort of study year, as the sentence is talking about John studying till F5 then going to the US to finish his studies.